# Integration with trigonometric functions question

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, area, trigonometric-integrals

I'm having trouble solving part (2). How do I do it?
I don't get where the integrations numbers came from (2/3,1) and this new equation for integration too. How do I find the value of $x = \alpha$ if it's not an rational angle?
I want to understand how I can comprehend and reach the answer myself.

**The original question, part (1) has been solved:**

> Consider
> $$f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{(3-2\cos x)}$$
> when $0\leq x \leq \pi$
>
> **$(1):$**
> $$f'(x) = \frac{3\cos x-2}{(3-2\cos x)^2}$$
>
> Let $ \alpha$ be the value of $x$ at which $f(x)$ has a local extremum. Then we have $\cos\alpha = \frac{2}{3}$
>
> **$(2):$**
>
> The portion of the plane bounded by the graph of the function $y = f(x)$ and the $X$ axis is divided into $2$ parts by the straight line $x = \alpha$. Let $S_1$ be the area of the part located at the left side of the line. Then we have
> $$S_1 = \int_{\frac{G}{H}}^{I} \frac{dt}{J-Kt}=\frac{L}{N}\log\left(\frac{M}{O}\right)$$
> Let $S_2$ be the area of the part located on the right side. We have
> $$S_2=\frac{P}{2}\log(Q)$$

The letters stand for $G=2, H=3, I=1, J=3, K=2, L=1, M=2, N=5, O=3, P=1, Q=3.$

[question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9yUX.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome! Could you type up your question with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? Your image is very low resolution, and it's really hard to follow what's happening with all of the random letters. People will be more likely to answer your question if you make it easier for them to read it!

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct it right away

Comment: In part (2) you are expected to make a change of variable using a trigonometric substitution, changing the variable from $x$ to $t$.

Comment: Alright, it worked properly. It got to the integration equation. Now about the integration limits, shouldn't the bounds be 0 to $\alpha$ (which is $arccos\frac{2}{3}$)? Why it's $\frac{2}{3}$ to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_1 = \int_0^{\cos^{-1}{\frac{2}{3}}} \frac{\sin x}{3-2\cos x}dx$$

Let $\cos x = t$

$\implies -\sin x dx = dt$

When $x=0 \to t = 1$ and $x=\arccos \frac{2}{3} \to t = \frac{2}{3}$ using our subsitution above to define the limits of $t$ after the change in variable

$$S_1 = -\int_1^{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{dt}{3-2t} = \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^1 \frac{dt}{3-2t}$$

Similarly for $S_2$